# Keypad open and closes and couldn't type in few android phones on my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app, android-keypad

Only in few android phones facing this issue in others it is working fine. I am in flutter version  3.19.0.
I couldn't replicate the issue in any phones. Having this issue for quite some time now.

Need to figure out a solution and fix the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.